# Prob(default in 1 year) given Prob(default in 1st 6mo)=Prob(default in 2nd 6mo)=10%?

Tags: probability

I cannot get my head around the following question. I've solved it in 2 different ways (with two different results) and I'm not convinced of either solution.

**Question:**
A company has 10% probability of defaulting in the first 6 months and 10% probability of defaulting for the second 6 months. What is the probability of defaulting over 1 year?

**Solution 1:**

*Events:*
$$\begin{align}
D_{1/12}&=\text{"Company defaults over 1 year"}\\
D_{1/6}&=\text{"Company defaults on first 6 months"}\\
D_{7/12}&=\text{"Company defaults on second 6 months"}\\
N_{1/6}&=\text{"Company doesn't default on first 6 months"}\\
N_{7/12}&=\text{"Company doesn't default on second 6 months"}\\
\end{align}$$

I've written all the possible events ($\Omega=D_{1/6}\cup D_{7/12}\cup N_{1/6}\cup N_{7/12}=\text{space of events}$) because I want to use the [*law of total probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

I calculate a term I need later:
$$\begin{align}P(\Omega)=&P(D_{1/6}\cup D_{7/12}\cup N_{1/6}\cup N_{7/12})\\=&P(D_{1/6})+P(D_{7/12})+P(N_{1/6})+P(N_{7/12})=1\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}P(N_{1/6})+P(N_{7/12})=1-[P(D_{1/6})+P(D_{7/12})]=80\%\end{align}$$

Law of total probability (I've put a question mark above an equal sign because I'm not sure of that passage):
$$\begin{align}P(D_{1/12})=&{P(D_{1/12}|D_{1/6})}\cdot P(D_{1/6})+P(D_{1/12}|D_{7/12})\cdot P(D_{7/12})+\\&P(D_{1/12}|N_{1/6})\cdot P(N_{1/6})+P(D_{1/12}|N_{7/12})\cdot P(N_{7/12})\\\stackrel{?}{=}&1\cdot 10\%+1\cdot 10\%+\\&P(D_{7/12})\cdot P(N_{1/6})+P(D_{1/6})\cdot P(N_{7/12})\\=&20\%+10\%\cdot [P(N_{1/6})+P(N_{7/12})]\\=&20\%+10\%\cdot 80\%=28\%\end{align}$$

In particular, can I write the following?

$$\begin{align}P(D_{1/12}|N_{1/6})&\stackrel{?}{=}P(D_{7/12})\\
P(D_{1/12}|N_{7/12})&\stackrel{?}{=}P(D_{1/6})\end{align}$$

**Solution 2:**

In case I use the [*inclusion–exclusion principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) I get:

$$\begin{align}P(D_{1/12})=&P(D_{1/6} \cup D_{7/12})=P(D_{1/6}) + P(D_{7/12})-P(D_{1/6} \cap D_{7/12})\\=&10\%+10\%-0\%\\=&20\%\end{align}$$

Comment: The question is not sufficiently clearly worded. Is it possible for them to default in both periods? If so, do we want the probability they default on both periods or on any period? If not, is the 10% for the second period conditional on not defaulting in the first or unconditional?

Comment: I would interpret this as follows: the company will default 10% of the time in the first 6 months, and of the remaining 90% of the time, will default 10% of those times, for a total of 0.1+0.1(0.9) = 0.19 = 19%. The problem in your last equation is that if you assume it can't default twice (i.e. intersection empty), then P(default 7/12) is less than 10% (since the 10% would be P(default 7/12 | no default 1/6) ), or else you could allow defaults in both halves, in which case intersection is not empty. Assuming independence, for example, gives 0.1+0.1-0.01 =0.19 again.